# WxPython: How do I Edit Row and Column Names for a cSheet Grid and make the cells non-editable?

Tags: wxpython, spreadsheet, wxwidgets

I am currently piping information to a wxPython GUI program in real time. I would like to make a custom spread-sheet-style 4x4 cell grid that continuously displays the values for a matrix being updated and sent to the GUI. Is it possible to edit the default row and column names (from 1234 and ABCD to ACGT and ACGT for example) for a wxPython cSheet and to make the cells non-editable?

Any suggestions or advice would be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

`wx.lib.sheet.CSheet` class extends `wx.grid.Grid`, there are `SetColLabelValue` and `SetRowLabelValue` methods:

```
names = 'ACGT'
sheet = CSheet(panel)
for index, name in enumerate(names):
    sheet.SetColLabelValue(index, name)
    sheet.SetRowLabelValue(index, name)
sizer.Add(sheet)
```

You can make cells non-editable by calling `SetReadOnly` method on each cell.

UPD: As @VZ. has noted: `EnableEditing(false)` makes your grid non-editable.

Comment: To make the entire grid read-only it's simpler to call `EnableEditing(false)`.

Comment: Thank you, I've included your comment to the answer.